# How update imageView in ViewController from Struct

Tags: swift, view

How to update imageView in ViewController from Struct

1. At ViewController method from struct catch URL

   ```
   func showAll() {
    GetManager.showContent(pasteboard: link)
   }
   ```
2. Next method from struct validation it, parse JSON and get a response from server with base64 data

   ```
     Alamofire.request(postURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
       switch response.result { ...
       }
      }
   ```
3. After this decoding images and video

   ```
   static func base64toImage(base64String: String?) -> UIImage{
   }

   static func base64toVideo(base64String: String?) {
   }
   ```
4. How correct to show/update - UI/imageView at ViewController. Now when I send a uiimage to view controller imageView it didn't change and not display the image. Want to solve this without notifications

Comment: you can try using closures or using delegates

Comment: @achu How to initialize if it closures, if it at viewdidload

Comment: I am not sure whether this will help. Please check it out https://github.com/achuaswani/CarouselApp.git

Comment: @achu Your answer help, but I need 1 more clarification https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280894/dynamic-link-at-mvc-model