# Dynamic Link at MVC model

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, struct

How at this example send dynamic link to service class any time and after this update view
I received link any time and I dont want to use notification and etc

1. View

   ```
   var viewModel = HomeViewModel()

    func configureViewModel() {
        viewModel.resultClosure = { [weak self] listModel in
            guard let image = listModel.uiImage else { return }
            self?.updateImageViewConstraint(nil, image: image)
        }
    }
   ```
2. HomveViewModel

   ```
   class HomeViewModel {
    var service = Services()
    var listModel = [ListModel]() {
           didSet {
               DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                   guard let self = self else {
                       return
                   }
                    self.resultClosure?(self.listModel[0])
               }
           }
       }

    let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
    var updatedImge : UIImage?
    var resultClosure: ((ListModel) -> Void)?
    var stringUrl: StringUrl!

    func fetchData() {
        service.makeRequest() { (result: Result<[ListModel]>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let listModel):
                self.listModel = listModel                    
                return
            case .failure(let error):
                print("\n HomeViewModel fetchData failure \(error) \n")
                return
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }
3. Services - Here I need to check the dynamic link

   ```
   class Services {
    let urlSession: URLSession
    let imageProvider = ImageProvider()
    let dynamicLinkfromStruct = "Dynamic Link From Struct!!!" 


    init(urlSession: URLSession = .shared) {
        self.urlSession = urlSession
    }


    func makeRequest(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[ListModel]>) -> Void) {


    guard let url = URL(string: dynamicLinkfromStruct) else { return } 

        imageProvider.loadImages(from: url) { (image) in
            do {
                let result = [ListModel.init(imageUrl: self.url, uiImage: image)] 
                completionHandler(.success(result))
            } catch {
                completionHandler(.failure(error ))
            }
        }
    }
   }
   ```
4. Model

   ```
   struct ListModel {

    let imageUrl: String?
    let uiImage: UIImage?
   }
   ```
5. Struct where I catch any time dynamic links which I need to show at View. Question here!
   How to Send Link to Services and update View???

   ```
   struct GetManager {
    static func showContent(pasteboard: String) {
    switch onlyLinkAbsoluteString.validURL {
           case true:
    // How to Send Link to Services and update View???
    }
    }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In MVVM/MVC communication should take this path

View > ViewModel > Manager > Service

Create an instance of your Manager in your ViewModel and an Instance of your Service in your Manager

You call the Manager's function in your ViewModel and the Manager would handle the communication with your Service.

Comment: Thank U for reply look pls for this https://monosnap.com/file/agDbGydcutDeiDCzfRAL6F2hYbDBQ7

Comment: To help you we need a minimum reproducible product. Something we can copy and paste in one or two steps and have a fully functional product with the least amount of code. I can't copy and paste images.